# .launch file associated while using a sensor

Tags: sensors, ros

What is the general *structure* of **.launch** file for using a sensor?

*For example:*

1.Following code is example for using a JoyStick to control TurtleSim

```
<launch>
  <node pkg="turtlesim" type="turtlesim_node" name="sim"/>
  <node pkg="chapter4_tutorials" type="example1" name="example1" />
  <param name="axis_linear" value="1" type="int" />
  <param name="axis_angular" value="0" type="int" />
  <node respawn="true" pkg="joy"type="joy" name="teleopJoy">
    <param name="dev" type="string" value="/dev/input/js0" />
    <param name="deadzone" value="0.12" />
  </node>
</launch>
```

2.Using a Laser Range finder

```
<launch>
  <node pkg="hokuyo_node" type="hokuyo_node" name="hokuyo_node"/>
  <node pkg="rviz" type="rviz" name="rviz"
        args="-d $(find chapter4_tutorials)/example2.vcg"/>
  <node pkg="chapter4_tutorials" type="example2" name="example2" />
</launch>
```

What exactly is the **syntax**?

Why do we have two **`<node pkg>`**?

Comment: http://answers.ros.org is the best place to ask this.

Answer (score 1):

The first node, hokuyo_node, is the driver for the sensor.
The second node, rviz, is for visualizing the data coming from the hokuyo_node.
The third node is the tutorial program.

The [launch file](http://wiki.ros.org/roslaunch)  format is well documented. However it assumes that you understand the basic organization of ROS, what nodes are, and how they interact.

Comment: Where can I find documentation for launch file format?

Comment: Both Google search, and the search tool of wiki.ros.org give good results.